# Setting attribute of SVG element with JS not working

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to add an `xlink:href` attribute to an SVG element from JS, but it's not working.

Here is my code:

test.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload=setupSvgLink()>
        <object id="test-svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
function setupSvgLink() {
    var svg = document.getElementById("test-svg").contentDocument;
    var waldo = svg.getElementById("waldo");
    waldo.setAttribute("xlink:href", "waldo.html");
}
```

test.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="80">
    <a id="waldo"><rect x="10" y="10" width="60" height="60" fill="blue"/></a>
</svg>
```

I am testing this with Firefox 20. I load `test.html`, but the rectangle does not have a link on it. I have checked in the Firefox Developer Tools' Inspector that the xlink:href attribute does appear on the element, but there is no link.

If I add the xlink:href attribute into the SVG file instead of doing it via JS it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with SVG you usually need to use `element.setAttributeNS`, change your function...

```
function setupSvgLink() {
    var xlinkns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
    var svg = document.getElementById("test-svg").contentDocument;
    var waldo = svg.getElementById("waldo");
    waldo.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, "href", "waldo.html");
}
```

Comment: That worked with one modification: the namespace needed to be `http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink`. Thanks!

Comment: @HighCommander4 Ah now I see, I've modified the answer. When changing SVG attributes preceded by a namespace (such as `xlink`) you use the corresponding namespace. Otherwise it's the SVG namespace. You learn something new every day!